# boto3 list all accounts in an organization

Tags: token, boto3, aws-organizations

I have a requirement that I want to list all the accounts and then write all the credentials in my `~/.aws/credentials` file. Fir this I am using `boto3` in the following way

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('organizations')
response = client.list_accounts(
    NextToken='string',
    MaxResults=123
)
print(response)
```

This fails with the following error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the ListAccounts operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

The question is , which token is it looking at? And if I want information about all accounts what credentials should I be using in the `credentials` file or the `config` file?

Comment: comment the NextToken='string', #NextToken='string',

Comment: did not make any difference, where is it reading credentials from?

Answer (score 12):

You can use boto3 **paginators** and **pages**.

Get an organizations object by using an aws configuration profile in the master account:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=master_acct)
client = session.client('sts')
org = session.client('organizations')
```

Then use the org object to get a paginator.

```
paginator = org.get_paginator('list_accounts')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
```

Then iterate through every page of accounts.

```
for page in page_iterator:        
    for acct in page['Accounts']:
        print(acct) # print the account
```

I'm not sure what you mean about "getting credentials". You can't get someone else's credentials. What you can do is list users, and if you want then list their access keys. That would require you to assume a role in each of the member accounts.

From within the above section, you are already inside a for-loop of each member account. You could do something like this:

```
id = acct['Id']
role_info = {
    'RoleArn': f'arn:aws:iam::{id}:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole',
    'RoleSessionName': id
}


credentials = client.assume_role(**role_info)

member_session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
    region_name='us-east-1'
)
```

However please note, that the role specified `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` needs to actually be present in every account, and your user in the master account needs to have the privileges to assume this role.

Once your prerequisites are setup, you will be iterating through every account, and in each account using `member_session` to access boto3 resources in that account.

Comment: Thanks thats very useful , but running this gives me an error that I am not authorized to perform the "assumerole" operation