# How to fetch specific AWS Account Tags using boto3 in all accounts present in an AWS Organization / specific Organization Unit

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a nested AWS Organization Structure and I want to fetch all internal accounts that reside in the Organizational Unit based on their category tags. Just wondering how to achieve it using a lambda written using Python Boto3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914154/boto3-list-all-accounts-in-an-organization

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***[get_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html?highlight=resourcegroupstaggingapi#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.get_resources)*** function and filter the result via ***TagFilters*** :

```
response = client.get_resources(
    PaginationToken='string',
    TagFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'name',
            'Values': [
                'me',
            ]
        },
    ],
    ResourcesPerPage=123,
    TagsPerPage=123,
    ResourceTypeFilters=[
        'string',
    ],
    IncludeComplianceDetails=True|False,
    ExcludeCompliantResources=True|False,
    ResourceARNList=[
        'string',
    ]
)
```